# Few questions about working with Git

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am a web-developer.
I am currently working as follows:
connected via FTP to the site directory on the server => download project (part of project) => develop new modules => uploaded complete modules (few files) to the server. My colleagues are developing other modules on this site and use the same algorithm.

I know it's bad, and the old way.
I want to organize the development process using a version control system (Git).

I've heard that it makes so:
We have the application development process, there are two main branches of the *master* and the *dev*.
My colleagues and I cloned main branch *dev*, create a local branch of a temporary new functionality or a patch, develop, make commits, then make the merge a temporary local branch with a main remote branch *dev*.
1) Am I right?

2)
I know that branch *dev* and *master* working with files from one repository - one directory.

Document root of my site and document root of subdomen of my site - this is different directories

I want my main domain site had the current stable version of the site, but a subdomain of my site referred to the development version of the site. How is it organized? How to do it?

3)
If I am not mistaken, a central repository is typically stored on github.com
How to link the main repository and directory site? Upload files from the repository to hosting manually ?
Whether to keep the site's directory on git hub? It may be better to use a repository within the local network?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of good questions! To answer them one by one.

Yes, your general understanding is right - that's one way to use Git. For a more detailed explanation of a workflow like this, check out Git-Flow: [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow). The branches are typically called *master* and *develop*. In addition to that, you will be working with *feature* and *release* branches.

With regards to your stable (*master*) and unstable (*develop*) branches in different directories, here's what you can do: Clone the repository twice, i.e. once in each directory on the server. In the stable directory, you check out the *master* branch, and in the unstable directory, you check out the *develop* branch. This way, you can keep both separate and also update them on demand. You could also look into tools/scripts that update/pull automatically whenever the branch is changed.

For the hosting, there are several options, I'll list the most common/popular ones:

- GitHub: By default (with free accounts), all repos on GitHub are public. This is great for open source, but might not be what you want. Paid accounts include private repos.
- [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/): The free account here includes private repos as well, this might be better suited for you. There are probably other services that offer this as well.
- Hosting your own: You can use a paid tool like GitHub Enterprise or Atlassian Stash, or there are free/open source tools like [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) that you can use to host your own repo. This might be the best if you plan to do more in this area, but it's also more complex to set up and maintain. Hosting your own has the advantage that you can easily deploy to your server through a post-hook.

I would start with something like BitBucket and then think about next steps.